# Why is the '.value' property not working?

Tags: javascript

```js
function updateCartTotal() {
  var cartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('center-cart-items')[0]
  var cartRows          = cartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('cart-row')
  for (var i = 0; i < cartRows.length; i++) {
    var cartRow         = cartRows[i]
    var priceElement    = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-price')[0]
    var quantityElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0]
    var price           = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace('$', ''))
    var quantity        = quantityElement.value
    console.log(price * quantity)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="center-cart-items">
<div class="cart-row"> 
  <div class="cart-item cart-column"> 
    <img class="cart-item-image" src="#" width="100" height="100" /> 
    <span class="cart-item-title"> T-shirt</span> 
  </div> 
  <span class="cart-price cart-column"> $29.99</span> 
  <div class="cart-quantity cart-column"> 
    <input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" value="2" /> 
    <button class="btn-remove" role="button">REMOVE</button>
  </div>   
</div>
```

When I run the code, I get a source error that says
`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')`
Not sure what is going on here, I am new to all of this and following guides to help me build.

Comment: We will need to see your html

Comment: <div class="cart-row">
                <div class="cart-item cart-column">
                    <img class="cart-item-image" src="#" width="100" height="100" />
                    <span class="cart-item-title"> T-shirt</span>
                </div>
                <span class="cart-price cart-column"> $29.99</span>
                <div class="cart-quantity cart-column">
                    <input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" value="2" />
                    <button class="btn-remove" role="button">REMOVE</button>
                </div>
            </div>

Comment: Please edit your question and add the html in there.

Comment: As far as I can tell this _should_ work fine. Can you `console.log(cartRow.innerHTML)` to see if it's really what you're expecting?

Comment: the code displayed here does not reproduce your error

Comment: console.log() is your friend, but that error is telling you it can not find the element

Answer (score 0):

The bug occurs before the reference to `cartRows`. There is no `.center-cart-items` class in the snippet you gave, and if you delete the reference to it, your code works fine (see snippet).

Check your complete html source, the js reference to assign `cartItemContainer` is probably the problem.

```js
function updateCartTotal() {
  //var cartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('center-cart-items')[0]
  var cartRows          = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-row')
  for (var i = 0; i < cartRows.length; i++) {
    var cartRow         = cartRows[i]
    var priceElement    = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-price')[0]
    var quantityElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0]
    var price           = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace('$', ''))
    var quantity        = quantityElement.value
    console.log(price * quantity)
  }
return (price * quantity);
}

console.log(updateCartTotal());
```

```html
<div class="cart-row"> 
  <div class="cart-item cart-column"> 
    <img class="cart-item-image" src="#" width="100" height="100" /> 
    <span class="cart-item-title"> T-shirt</span> 
  </div> 
  <span class="cart-price cart-column"> $29.99</span> 
  <div class="cart-quantity cart-column"> 
    <input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" value="2" /> 
    <button class="btn-remove" role="button">REMOVE</button>
  </div>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have recreated your code in codePen and it works fine:

https://codepen.io/SweetChillyPhilly/pen/xxpjyNQ

```
<div class="center-cart-items">
  <div class="cart-row"> 
    <div class="cart-item cart-column"> 
      <img class="cart-item-image" src="#" width="100" height="100" /> 
      <span class="cart-item-title"> T-shirt</span> 
    </div> 
    <span class="cart-price cart-column"> $29.99</span> 
    <div class="cart-quantity cart-column"> 
      <input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" value="2" /> 
      <button class="btn-remove" role="button">REMOVE</button>
    </div>   
  </div>
  <div class="cart-row"> 
    <div class="cart-item cart-column"> 
      <img class="cart-item-image" src="#" width="100" height="100" /> 
      <span class="cart-item-title"> T-shirt</span> 
    </div> 
    <span class="cart-price cart-column"> $29.99</span> 
    <div class="cart-quantity cart-column"> 
      <input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" value="2" /> 
      <button class="btn-remove" role="button">REMOVE</button>
    </div>   
  </div>
  <div class="cart-row"> 
    <div class="cart-item cart-column"> 
      <img class="cart-item-image" src="#" width="100" height="100" /> 
      <span class="cart-item-title"> T-shirt</span> 
    </div> 
    <span class="cart-price cart-column"> $29.99</span> 
    <div class="cart-quantity cart-column"> 
      <input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" value="2" /> 
      <button class="btn-remove" role="button">REMOVE</button>
    </div>   
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function updateCartTotal() {
  var cartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('center-cart-items')[0]
  var cartRows          = cartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('cart-row')
  for (var i = 0; i < cartRows.length; i++) {
    var cartRow         = cartRows[i]
    var priceElement    = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-price')[0]
    var quantityElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0]
    var price           = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace('$', ''))
    var quantity        = quantityElement.value
    console.log(price * quantity)
  }
}

updateCartTotal();
```

Your console log is working as expected.

So i suspect your issue lies outside of this code.